# Optimizing Wide Layout Scaling: Achieving 100% Viewport Coverage?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The code maintains the aspect ratio, but sometimes it doesn't reach all the way to the edges, and there would be empty spaces at the top/bottom/sides.

How do I get it to do like this example animated gif?

[image]

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
        body {
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
            height: 100vh;
            margin: 0;
        }

        .rectangle {
            width: 100vmin;
            height: 56.25vmin;
            background-color: #66ccff;
            display: flex;
            justify-content: center;
            align-items: center;
        }

        .rectangle-text {
            font-size: 15vmin;
            font-weight: bold;
            font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
        }
    </style>
    <title>Rectangle</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="rectangle">
        <span class="rectangle-text">RECTANGLE</span>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```